# Reducing data usage of Scrapy Spider/How to be a better internet citizen?

Tags: python, scrapy

I recently resurrected an old scrapy spider (`0.18.4`) that crawls craigslist. The spider grabs links from the first page of apartment listings every 15mins, and scrapes the links of new postings. (see code below)

This spider was downloading `>1GB` of data every 15min! I was able to reduce it by half, but this is still a lot of load on the craigslist site. Please note, this is from the spider alone, as I tested without pipelines enabled. I have also tried limiting through `MAX_DEPTH` and `DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE` in `settings.py`, spider class settings, and individual follow on requests meta settings. I have spent several hours in the docs, messed around with `Rules`, updated to the latest version of scrapy, etc.; all to no avail. Granted, I wrote this script several years ago when I was new to python, but perhaps my folly can be the comunities gain...

Given my code below, what can I, or anyone else using scrapy, do to reduce the amount of data I'm downloading, when I only care about a couple kB of text???? Which calls are data greedy?

Spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
#from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from craigslist_2br.items import CraigslistItem
from craigslist_2br import craigslistTools
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urljoin
import types
import exceptions
import datetime
import ipdb as pdb
#from ghost import Ghost

class Suppressor:
    def __init__(self, exception_type,localList):
        self._exception_type = exception_type
        self.safe_dict = dict([ (k, locals().get(k, None)) for k in localList ])

    def __call__(self, expression):
        try:
            exec(expression, {"__builtins__" : None}, self.safe_dict)
        except self._exception_type as e:
            print 'Suppressor: suppressed exception %s with content \'%s\'' % (type(self._exception_type), e)

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa/"]
    #g=Ghost()

    def parse(self, response):
        hxsM = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        ##titles = hxs.select('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]')
        postings=hxsM.select('//p[@class="result-info"]')
        resultRows=hxsM.select('//li[@class="result-row"]')
        try:
            IDf=open("/home/dapper/python/scrapy/scrapy_craig2br/craigslist_2br/craigslist_2br/postingIDs.txt","r")
            IDvec=[int(sl.strip("\n")) for sl in IDf.readlines()]
        except:
            IDvec=[]
        finally:
            try:
                IDf.close()
            except:
                pass

        for posting,resultRow in zip(postings,resultRows):            
            item = CraigslistItem()
            try:
                item["ID"]=posting.select("a/@data-id").extract()[0]
                if (int(item["ID"])==int(resultRow.select("@data-pid").extract()[0])):
                    try:
                        item["repostID"]=resultRow.select("@data-repost-of").extract()[0]
                    except:
                        item["repostID"]=''
                else:
                    item["repostID"]=''
            except:
                item["ID"]=''
                item["repostID"]=''

            try:
                item ["price"] = posting.select("span[@class='result-meta']/span[@class='result-price']/text()").extract()[0]
            except:
                item ["price"] = 0

            try:
                item ["neighborhood"] = posting.select("span[@class='result-meta']/span[@class='result-hood']/text()").extract()[0]
            except:
                item ["neighborhood"] = ''

            if ((not any(item["ID"]) or (int(item["ID"]) not in IDvec)) and 
                (craigslistTools.FixPriceStr(item['price'])<3000.0) and 
                (not((any(item["repostID"]) and (int(item["repostID"]) in IDvec)) and (any(item['neighborhood']) and craigslistTools.outDaHoods(item['neighborhood']))))):
                #s = Suppressor(exception_type=exceptions.IndexError,localList=[item,titles,postings]) # TODO: put your exception type here
                item ["title"] = posting.select("a/text()").extract()[0]
                item ["link"] = posting.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
                item ["dateAdded"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
                try:
                    item ["size"] = posting.select("span[@class='result-meta']/span[@class='housing']/text()").extract()[0]
                except:
                    item ["size"] = ''
                if item['link']:
                    if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                        if isinstance(item['link'], types.StringTypes):
                            item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                        else:
                            item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'][0])
                    yield Request(item['link'],
                                  meta={'item': item,'download_maxsize':8**8,'depth_limit':1},
                                  callback=self.anchor_page)



    def anchor_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        old_item = response.request.meta['item'] # Receiving parse Method item that was in Request meta
        # parse some more values
        #place them in old_item
        #e.g
        old_item['postingbody']=hxs.select("//section [@id='postingbody']").extract()

        try:
            latit=float(hxs.select("//div [@id='map']//@data-latitude").extract()[0])
            longi=float(hxs.select("//div [@id='map']//@data-longitude").extract()[0])
            #print '%f,%f'%(latit,longi)
        except:
            latit=0
            longi=0

        try:
            old_item["address"] = hxs.select(".//div [@class='mapaddress']/text()").extract()[0]
        except:
            old_item["address"] = []
        try:    
            if any(latit)&(not any([char.isdigit() for char in old_item["address"][0]])):
                try:
                    old_item["address"] = craigslistTools.coord2addr(latit,longi)
                except:
                    pass
            elif (not any(old_item["address"])):
                try:
                    zips=[94611,94610,94609,94606,94618,94705]
                    for z in zips:
                        for line in old_item['postingbody'].split("\n"):
                            if str(z) in line:
                              old_item["address"] = line
                except:
                    pass
        except:
            pass

        if (latit==0)&(any(old_item["address"])):
            try:
                cities=['Oakland','oakland','Piedmont','piedmont','Berkeley','berkeley','montclair','Montclair']
                if not any([c in old_item["address"] for c in cities]):
                    old_item["address"]+=', Oakland'
                geoRes=Geocoder.geocode(old_item["address"])
                latit=geoRes[0].latitude
                longi=geoRes[0].longitude
            except:
                pass

        old_item["latit"] = latit
        old_item["longi"] = longi

        try:
            (bartDist,bartCoord)=craigslistTools.bartDist((latit,longi))
        except:
            bartDist=0
        try:
            if ((bartDist!=0) and (bartDist<2)):
                bartWalkingTime=craigslistTools.bartWalking((latit,longi),bartCoord)
            else:
                bartWalkingTime=0
        except:
            bartWalkingTime=0
        old_item["bartDist"] = bartDist
        old_item["BartWalkingTime"] = bartWalkingTime

        try:
            if ((bartDist<1) and (bartDist!=0)):
                old_item['LLNLDrivingTime']=craigslistTools.LLNLdriving((latit,longi))
            else:
                old_item['LLNLDrivingTime']=0
        except:
            old_item['LLNLDrivingTime']=0

        try:
            old_item["Br"]=int(hxs.select("//p [@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0].strip('BR'))
            old_item["baths"]=int(hxs.select("//p [@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[1].strip('Ba'))
        except:
            try:
                old_item["Br"]=int(re.findall(r"(\d+)br",old_item['size'])[0])
                old_item["baths"]=1
            except:
                old_item["Br"]=-1
                old_item["baths"]=-1

        try:
            old_item['amenities']=hxs.select("//p [@class='attrgroup']/span/text()").extract()
        except:
            old_item['amenities']=[]

        yield old_item
```

settings.py:

```
# Scrapy settings for craigslist_2br project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
# default. All the other settings are documented here:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#

BOT_NAME = 'craigslist_2br'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['craigslist_2br.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'craigslist_2br.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'craigslist_2br.pipelines.Craigslist2BrPipeline':0}

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'craigslist_2br (+http://www.craigslist.org)'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1 #  Default: 8
#SCHEDULER = 'scrapy.core.scheduler.Scheduler'
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
DEPTH_LIMIT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news! The problem I experienced will likely not effect you (just what you wanted to read when searching for answers ;) ) Using the Depreciated `HtmlXPathSelector` from `v0.18` can cause major issues (surprise surprise), so don't do it.